# What is the relation between a line in cpu cache and a page in main memory (and block in disk)?

Tags: memory, devices, disk, cache, storage

[Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (2nd Edition) [Randal E. Bryant, David R. O'Hallaron]](http://gec.di.uminho.pt/Discip/MaisAC/CS-APP_Bryant/csapp.ch6.pdf) says

> **A block** is a ﬁxed-sized packet of information that moves back and
>   forth between a cache and main memory (or a lower-level cache).
>
> A line is a container in a cache that stores a block, as well as other
>   information such as the valid bit and the tag bits.

1. I understand that a block is often used as a unit in a disk. Is there some relation between the block used here and a block in a disk?  Do they have the same size?
2. A page frame is a unit in a main memory. What is the relation
   between a block/line in a cache and a page frame in a main memory? Do they have the same size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of these sizes you ask about are variable, and implementation specific.

No, the use of "block" in this situation is not related to the block size on a permanent storage device. In that case, a block is the smallest amount of bits that can be modified at one time. For example, if you have a block size of 16KB on a filesystem, then no file can take up less than 16KB.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537579/file-system-block-size

I'm not as familiar with the relationship between a cache block and a memory page, but presumably the cache line will be smaller than or equal to the memory page, as a cache is a subset of data from memory.

Comment: Thanks. A main memory is a "subset" of data from a disk, in the same sense as "a cache is a subset of data from memory". But a page in a main memory is bigger than a block in a disk